# How to parse signedCookies in express?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, cookie-httponly

I send a cookie to my front-end thanks to express:

```js
  // signing the token
  static generateToken(user: PartialUser): Cookie {
    return jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_TOKEN_KEY, {
      expiresIn: "14d",
    });
    
  // sending the cookie
  return res
      .status(200)
      .cookie("myApp", token, {
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + msPerDay * 14),
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
      })
      .json({ user });
    
  // initializing cookie parser in index.js:
  app.use(cookieParser(process.env.JWT_TOKEN_KEY));
  
  //parsing the cookie
  const authenticate = (req: Authenticate, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const { myApp } = req.signedCookies; 
  if (req.signedCookies) {
    return jwt.verify(
      myApp,
      process.env.JWT_TOKEN_KEY,
      (error, parsedToken) => {
        if (error) {
          return res.sendStatus(403);
        }

        req.cookie = { _id: parsedToken._id };
        return next();
      }
    );
  }
  return res.sendStatus(401);
};
```

The `req.signedCookies` object is always empty. So all my routes return a 403 - forbidden access. However, if I don't specify `secure: true` when sending the cookie, it works, because I can access it in `req.cookies`. The network tab shows that the cookie is correctly send along the client request.

How to fix this?

ps: I'm fine with using `req.cookies`, but my express server is hosted on Heroku and it never sends the cookie to the client, which is a custom https domain. This is why I'm trying the `secure:true` option. For now, it only works in localhost. Maybe the solution is elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cookie signature on one hand, and the `secure` option on the other hand, are actually two different things.

The `secure` option restricts the cookie to be sent over https only. This is intended at avoiding eavesdropping over the network. Incoming cookies that are set as `secure` will by default always be exposed on `req.cookies` by `cookie-parser`.

A cookie signature on the other hand is basically a cryptographic hash that is intended at making a cookie tamper-proof. It seems that with the `cookie-parser` package, you sign a cookie with the `signed: true` option. Only incoming cookies that have been explicitly signed will be exposed on `req.signedCookies`. Note this is all regardless of the `secure` option.